# make input and span next to each other

Tags: html, css

Trying to align input and span next to each other. Span is positioned below input ,how to align span on right side of input. I wanted to create a search bar with this input and span tag hence want to align next to each other

I have placed both of them inside one division yet it is not positioned correctly

is there any css property missing out or any css is given incorrectly in my code

```css
.modal-body .search-input{
  width:100%
}
#custom-search-input {
  margin:0;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 0;

}
.form-control{
  border-radius: 0;
}
#custom-search-input .search-query {
  padding-right: 3px;
  padding-right: 4px \9;
  padding-left: 3px;
  padding-left: 4px \9;
  border: 1px solid   #494949 ;
  /* border-right-style: none; */
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

#custom-search-input button {
  background-color:rgb(0,0,0,0.3) ;
  height: calc(1.5em + .75rem + 2px);
  padding: 2px 10px;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.ion-android-search{
  font-size: 150%;
}
.btn-danger{
  border:none;
  border-radius: 0;
}
.input-group-btn{
  float: right;
  position: relative;
}
.search-query:focus + button {
  z-index: 3;   
}
 .search-form {
  width: 80%;
}
.search-form input:focus + .results { display: block }

.search-form .results {
  display: none;
  /* position: absolute; */
  top: 35px;
  left: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 5px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #cbcfe2 #c8cee7 #c4c7d7;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #fdfdfd;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #fdfdfd), color-stop(100%, #eceef4));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fdfdfd, #eceef4);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fdfdfd, #eceef4);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fdfdfd, #eceef4);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fdfdfd, #eceef4);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #fdfdfd, #eceef4);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -ms-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -o-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.search-form .results li { display: block }

.search-form .results li:first-child { margin-top: -1px }

.search-form .results li:first-child:before, .search-form .results li:first-child:after {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border: 5px outset transparent;
}

.search-form .results li:first-child:before {
  border-bottom: 5px solid #c4c7d7;
  top: -2px;
}

.search-form .results li:first-child:after {
  border-bottom: 5px solid #fdfdfd;
  top: -10px;
}

.search-form .results li:first-child:hover:before, .search .results li:first-child:hover:after { display: none }

.search-form .results li:last-child { margin-bottom: -1px }

.search-form .results li {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 -1px;
  padding: 6px 40px 6px 10px;
  color: #808394;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-shadow: 0 1px #fff;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.search-form .results li span { font-weight: 200 }

.search-form .results li:before {
  content: '';
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 10px;
  margin-top: -9px;
  /* background: url("https://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/7/7BNkBjd.png") 0 0 no-repeat; */
}

.search-form .results li:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-color: #28be9a #28be9a #28be9a;
  background-color: #28be9a;
  /* background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #59aaf4), color-stop(100%, #338cdf));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #59aaf4, #338cdf);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #59aaf4, #338cdf);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #59aaf4, #338cdf);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #59aaf4, #338cdf);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #59aaf4, #338cdf); */
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  -ms-box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  -o-box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}

:-moz-placeholder {
  color: #a7aabc;
  font-weight: 200;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #a7aabc;
  font-weight: 200;
}

.lt-ie9 .search input { line-height: 26px }
```

```html
    <div class="modal fade" id="search-bar" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog search-modal">
                  <div class="modal-content search-modal">
                    <div class="modal-body">
<div id="custom-search-input">
                            <div class="input-group col-md-12 ">
                                <form class="search-form">
                                <input type="text" id="myInput" class="  search-query form-control search-input" placeholder="Search" />
                                <span class="input-group-btn">
                                    <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">
                                        <i class="ion-android-search "></i>
                                    </button>
                                </span>
                                <ul class="results" >
                               </ul>
                            </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                     </div> 
                </div>
              </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `display: flex;` to your `.search-form`

Take a look at flexbox, it is a more modern method for solving a lot of layout challenges.
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
#custom-search-input {
  margin:0;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 0;

}

.form-control{
  border-radius: 0;
}
#custom-search-input .search-query {
  padding-right: 3px;
  padding-right: 4px \9;
  padding-left: 3px;
  padding-left: 4px \9;
  border: 1px solid   #494949 ;
  /* border-right-style: none; */
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

#custom-search-input button {
  background-color:rgb(0,0,0,0.3) ;
  height: calc(1.5em + .75rem + 2px);
  padding: 2px 10px;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.ion-android-search{
  font-size: 150%;
}
.btn-danger{
  border:none;
  border-radius: 0;
}
.search-query:focus + button {
  z-index: 3;   
}
 .search-form {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.search-input{
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.search-form input:focus + .results { display: block }

.search-form .results {
  display: none;
  /* position: absolute; */
  top: 35px;
  left: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 5px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #cbcfe2 #c8cee7 #c4c7d7;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #fdfdfd;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #fdfdfd), color-stop(100%, #eceef4));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fdfdfd, #eceef4);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fdfdfd, #eceef4);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fdfdfd, #eceef4);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fdfdfd, #eceef4);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #fdfdfd, #eceef4);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -ms-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -o-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.search-form .results li { display: block }

.search-form .results li:first-child { margin-top: -1px }

.search-form .results li:first-child:before, .search-form .results li:first-child:after {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border: 5px outset transparent;
}

.search-form .results li:first-child:before {
  border-bottom: 5px solid #c4c7d7;
  top: -2px;
}

.search-form .results li:first-child:after {
  border-bottom: 5px solid #fdfdfd;
  top: -10px;
}

.search-form .results li:first-child:hover:before, .search .results li:first-child:hover:after { display: none }

.search-form .results li:last-child { margin-bottom: -1px }

.search-form .results li {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 -1px;
  padding: 6px 40px 6px 10px;
  color: #808394;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-shadow: 0 1px #fff;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.search-form .results li span { font-weight: 200 }

.search-form .results li:before {
  content: '';
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 10px;
  margin-top: -9px;
  /* background: url("https://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/7/7BNkBjd.png") 0 0 no-repeat; */
}

.search-form .results li:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-color: #28be9a #28be9a #28be9a;
  background-color: #28be9a;
  /* background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #59aaf4), color-stop(100%, #338cdf));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #59aaf4, #338cdf);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #59aaf4, #338cdf);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #59aaf4, #338cdf);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #59aaf4, #338cdf);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #59aaf4, #338cdf); */
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  -ms-box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  -o-box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}

:-moz-placeholder {
  color: #a7aabc;
  font-weight: 200;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #a7aabc;
  font-weight: 200;
}

.lt-ie9 .search input { line-height: 26px }
```

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="search-bar" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog search-modal">
                  <div class="modal-content search-modal">
                    <div class="modal-body">
<div id="custom-search-input">
                            <div class="input-group col-md-12 ">
                                <form class="search-form">
                                <input type="text" id="myInput" class="  search-query form-control search-input" placeholder="Search" />
                                <span class="input-group-btn">
                                    <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">
                                        <i class="ion-android-search "></i>
                                    </button>
                                </span>
                            </form>
                            <ul class="results" >
                              <li>Result</li>
                             </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                     </div> 
                </div>
              </div>
```

Comment: It would probably also be worth removing the `float: right` from the `span` element. It may be useful to add a brief explanation of _why_ using `flex` has resolved this for OP.

Comment: I have ul tag next that will also be positioned next if i add display:flex.But i want it to be below

Comment: @shee8 I have edited to fix, I added `flex-wrap: wrap;`

Comment: its again aligned below

Comment: I think removing position: absolute; from .search-form .results  will effect other css